# 'const' enums are not supported in storybook when using my Typescript Components

Tags: typescript, storybook

I have a typescript component with an enum :

```
  const enum blah {
    one = "one",
    two = "two"
  }
```

Without the typescript enum, the typscript component will compile and display correctly, but with the enum in the code it will not.

How do I make storybook understand enums in typescript?

Comment: Does it work if you make it a non-erased enum?  (e. g. `enum blah` instead of `const enum blah`)?

Comment: yes it does. but i am not sure if i am allowed to change the code

Comment: I think You should not change PROD code only for storybook

Comment: "const enum" is redundant right? Because an "enum" is implicitly a const anyway?

Comment: @OliverWatkins 
In TypeScript, `const enum` is a different data type from a simple `enum`, because the generated code is different: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums

Answer (score 0):

Storybook is using Babel for Typescript transpiling.

#### Using ts-loader

Customizing the storybook webpack configuration and using `ts-loader` instead of Babel did it for me. The rest of my project is also setup with `ts-loader` so you might have to look into how to setup the project with it.

```js
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  // ... other configuration here

  // Customize the webpack configuration
  webpackFinal: async(config) => {
    // We want to use ts-loader for tsx files
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
    });

    return config;
  }
};
```

#### Using Babel

I wasn't able to make it work with Babel, but [several comments on this issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12479#issuecomment-811435557) suggest to use [`babel-preset-const-enum`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-const-enum).

#### Sources

- [Storybook Webpack configuration](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack)
- [Issue which helped me figuring it out](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12479)